# Enlarging square of a responsive square layout

Tags: html, css

I've created a grid of responsive squares using width and padding-bottom.  I want to create a hover effect where the square that's hovered will enlarge slightly.  However, the way I've tried it makes the entire layout mess up when a square is hovered.  I tried to allow for more room by changing the margins when hovered as well but that didn't change anything.

Here's a jsFiddle of my code: https://jsfiddle.net/p3tcog0o/

HTML:

```
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.square{
  width:15%;
  padding-bottom:15%;
  background-color:red;
  float:left;
  margin:3%;
  transition: .5s width, .5s padding-bottom;

}
.square:hover{
  width:16%;
  padding-bottom:16%;
  margin:2%;
}
```

Comment: why not use css transform scale?

Comment: I wasn't aware of it's existence. That's what I'm using now :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `transform: scale()`

```css
.square{
  width:15%;
  padding-bottom:15%;
  background-color:red;
  float:left;
  margin:3%;
  transition: .5s width, .5s padding-bottom, .5s transform;
}
.square:hover{
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much!

Comment: Can you explain why this works? As in why it doesn't push the other elements as it gets bigger like changing the width and padding does? I tried to find the answer elsewhere but I couldn't :(

Comment: @Cylthus when in doubt, consult the spec. https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-css-transforms-1-20131126/#transform-rendering *"For elements whose layout is governed by the CSS box model, the transform property does not affect the flow of the content surrounding the transformed element."*